# Apply css last-child to an element that is not the immediate child in ul li

Tags: css, pseudo-class, css-selectors

I have this HTML --

```
<ul class="parent">
<li>
    <div class="child-1 x">
        <div class="child-2 x">test</div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="child-1 x">
        <div class="child-2 x">test</div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="child-1 x">
        <div class="child-2 x">test</div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

And this CSS --

```
.x{
    border:1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
.child-1:last-child{
    border-color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BDj2h/1/

Im trying to apply red border only to the last `child-1 div`. But its not happening. CSS `last-child` pseudo class checks whether its the last element inside its immediate parent, not in the whole DOM(which was my wrong understanding).

Any idea how to do this with css only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li:last-child .child-1
```

Would have the same effect.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ycXD/)

Answer (score 1):

[`:last-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo)<sup>1</sup> pseudo won't respect the last declared `class`, it just tracks the last instance of the element in the parent/child relation.

> <sup>1</sup> Same as `:nth-last-child(1)`. The :last-child pseudo-class represents an
>   element that is the last child of some other element.

So for example, if you've something like

Writing something like

```
div.wrap div.blow:last-child {
   /* .blow doesn't make any sense there, CSS will look up 
       for last div element nested inside .wrap */
}
```

In this case, you can try using

```
.parent li:last-child div[class^="child-1"] {
    border-color:red;
}
```

Or simply

```
.parent li:last-child div.child-1.x {
   border-color:red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BDj2h/4/)

---

Note: `last-child` is somewhat loose pseudo, as it will simply ignore the element if it's not the last child of the parent element, so here, `last-of-type` comes in to action where it selects `last type` of an `element` regardless of it's DOM level.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul li:last-child > div.child-1 {
    border-color:red;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BDj2h/3/